# No input fields in Django when making a form

Tags: django

I'm new to django and I'm trying to create forms, but whenever I run this I end up with a submit button with no input fields. If you see any other mistakes, don't hesitate to tell me.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .forms import *

def form(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forma(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('index.html')
else:
    form = forma()
return render(request, 'action.html', {"form":form})

def action(request):
    return render(request, 'action.html')
```

**forms.py **

```
from django import forms

class forma(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <section id = "sec">
    <h1>... </h1>
    <h3> ... </h3>
    <h4> ... <h4>
    <a href = "/papas"> <button> ... </button> </a>
    <p>{{hola}} alo {{darwich}}</p>
    <form action= "action.html" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
    </section>
<body>
```

Comment: What does action.html look like? That's the template you're rendering in that view.

Comment: action.html has nothing in it, just an h1 saying "Done." Should I render the view in index.html?

Comment: @JosephCohen Yes.